# Repetitive calling of SP within another SP is causing duplicate PK name issues in temp table in the the called SP when used in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, temp-tables

I have two SPs in SQL Server. SP1 calls SP2 repetitively in a loop with different parameters and keep storing the output of SP2 in a temp table.

SP2 which is being called repetitively by SP1 have some temp tables with "un-named" primary keys in it.

I know named primary keys on temp tables causes issues because sometimes they do not get dropped even if the temp table itself is dropped.

In SP2, at the very beginning, I do check and drop any temp tables in SP2 if they exist.

This seems to be working totally fine within SSMS but when I use SP1 in SSRS, several times it throws an error in SP2 for PK name violation.

> Cannot insert duplicate key in the object #tempTable.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: If you want to insert duplicate values into the temp table, then why are you setting that column as PK?  It seems like the answer here is to avoid that designation when the temp table is created, but it would be helpful if you could give an example of the structure of the temp table and the looping code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't define a primary key on your temp table.  The primary key constraint enforces uniqueness.  Instead, create a clustered index.  You'll still get the performance benefit of the query, but without the duplicate data error.

More than likely there are duplicates rows being generated so watch for duplicate data in your output.

Once you've resolved your duplicate data problem, you can reinstate the primary key to ensure an error is thrown on duplicate data in the future, or leave it as a clustered index and hope that your report consumer notices if data is being duplicated again.

Comment: The output is supposed to be unique, that is why I am using PK. While there can be still for some reason duplicate data in my test dataset but if there would be any duplicates then this SP should not run fine in SSMS either. Strangely just in SSRS this SP is throwing this error for the same parameters and same test dataset that runs fine in SSMS.

Comment: Remove the primary key temporarily to see what data is being duplicated.  That is the first step in determining how you are getting duplicates and what you need to do to resolve it.